# WebStorm Angular 13 async pipe: Missing require() statement

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular13

After updating to Angular 13, in my WebStorm the async pipe turned red with the message

> Missing require() statement

[image]

Also, all directives turned with a warning like

> No directive is matched on attribute ngIf

[image]

I've installed https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angular-and-angularjs again, restarted WebStorm, and nothing. I have WebStorm 2021.2.3

Note that compilation works fine, project works fine, I'm just getting these errors and warnings.

Going back in my commits to pre-update (Angular 12) and running `npm i` the red and warnings **disappear**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"I've installed https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angular-and-angularjs again"* It's a bundled plugin (comes with the IDE). If you try to install it over again this may easily break your setup and manual fixing (deleting the plugin files) may be needed. Please avoid doing that with **bundled** plugins.

Comment: BTW, 2021.3 should be released this month, most likely next week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm... it seems that Angular 13 is not yet supported

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53312?_ga=2.96724378.402765000.1636963958-943143576.1632898581

I've installed the Beta version https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/ (Build #WS-213.5744.37, built on November 11, 2021) and it works fine now. So, we need to wait for the next release.